# PageView - preserve page/change index while inserting new items

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

When adding new items to list, PageView index stays the same, but item 
with that index changes and I would like to avoid that behavior.

To be more specified those new items are inserted to the begging of the list.

Is there a way to preserve current page or method to change index to the right one so the page will stay the same?

Code below is just a simple implementation of this problem.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> pagesText = List.generate(10, (int index) => 'INDEX :: $index');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pagesText.insert(0, 'INDEX :: ${pagesText.length + 1}');
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: MyPageViewBuilder(pages: pagesText),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPageViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController = PageController(keepPage: true);

  final List<String> pages;

  MyPageViewBuilder({this.pages});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PageView.builder(
        controller: pageController,
        itemCount: pages.length,
        onPageChanged: (int index) {
          print('PageChanged $index');
        },
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Center(
            key: ValueKey(pages[index]),
            child: Text(pages[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `PageController.jumpToPage` after inserting new item. To do this though, you need to have access to `PageController` in your `MyAppState`.

Firstly, I added a new field to your `MyPageViewBuilder` and its constructor and removed the old `pageController` field:

```dart
// (...)
final PageController pageController;

MyPageViewBuilder({this.pages, this.pageController});
// (...)
```

Then, I added it to your `MyAppState`:

```dart
final pageController = PageController(keepPage: true);
```

and in `onPressed` I'm calling `PageController.jumpToPage`:

```dart
setState(() {
  pagesText.insert(0, 'INDEX :: ${pagesText.length + 1}');
  pageController.jumpToPage(pageController.page.round() + 1);
});
```

Comment: I've update the question, those new elements are inserted to the beginning of the list and that the case.